# Stop case side-panel from buzzing

Tags: desktop-computer, case

My desktop's case is a Cooler-Master Storm Scout 2. The removable top panel (the one that exposes fans mounted to the top of the case) often buzzes while my computer is running. I've verified that none of the cables are rubbing against the panel, so it's the case itself that is causing the buzzing.

I can stop the buzzing by pressing on the top panel with moderate pressure, or by tilting the tower very slightly in any direction. If I give the *side* panel a light whack, the buzzing will sometimes stop for anywhere between 1 and 10 minutes, but inevitably returns.

I've tried hacky workarounds like sticking something under one of the feet to give the tower a slight tilt, but these aren't real solutions. I move my tower frequently (which is why I selected one with a handle), so I'd rather find a better approach that doesn't require keeping the tower in a very specific position.

I feel like there's probably a very simple solution to this problem, but I sure can't think of one. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you checked that your case fans are attached snugly?

Comment: They are, and no fans are attached to the side panel.

Comment: Just as a double check, I would also verify that all other spinning things are secured properly, HDD's, dvd drives, cpu fan, and any addon cards that have fans such as a video card. Also make sure that the side panel is screwed on tightly, if the case is the type to screw down. Other than that I can't think of what would cause a buzzing in the case. Good luck.

Comment: I would also check to make and see if there is a cable that is touching the side of the case. If there is a cable touching the side of the case (more specifically a SATA or IDE power connector), it could be picking up vibration from somewhere, and then it transfers onto the side panel.

Comment: @DrZoo The buzzing is definitely coming from the top panel. There shouldn't be any cables touching up there. I checked that the cables weren't touching the side panel a million times and even tied them to the side of the HDD enclosure to keep them safely away from the outer part of the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have something physically loose or mis-aligned somewhere.  Make sure that things are screwed in snugly and that any panels or covers fit and close properly.

Go over everything in a methodical way, just to make sure you cover all the bases.  If you can't find it, some thin weather stripping might help along panel/cover edges.

Comment: I've tried and tried and I can't find anything loose. It's a (insert swears) nightmare to get the carrying handle off to be able to remove the top panel, and every time I do so I'm at risk of breaking the snaps that hold the handle in place. I did realize a month ago I had put the panel in backwards (it seems to fit the same either way, but has an arrow that is supposed to point towards the front of the tower). I switched the orientation and the buzzing actually stopped for weeks, but now it's back. I suppose I should check tightness again. Weather stripping is a great idea as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like resonance. The fans or hard drives are vibrating, which makes your entire case vibrate.

Making a PC silent is a very broad topic, there's entire sites dedicated to the subject. You can try muting the resonance by gluing some kind of foam to the panel, search the web for "pc case dampening foam". It also can't harm to clean the fans.

Comment: There's a fan directly underneath the panel, maybe it's causing the resonance. I tried unplugging it months ago and I didn't notice any improvement, so I ended up plugging it back it, but unplugging it again wouldn't hurt - I've never had any cooling issues anyway. The dampening foam sounds very interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Y900 Series Lenovo Legion. It’s the panel vibrating against metal frame of your case. It’s a design flaw with some of these modern tooless glass panels; there is way too much wiggle room between the panel and the case, where as before during the old days of tools, panels were fit tight against the frame because they were screwed on.

SOLUTION: electrical tape.

I did this with my PC and it works. Put black electrical tape against the inner edges of your outside panel. Across all four inner edges of your outside panel place a thick layer of black electrical tape. This will essentially act as a cushion between your panel and your case frame, preventing the metal of the frame from making contact with metal of the panel. Metal rattles, but plastic doesn't. The electrical tape will remove all the buzzing sound that the vibration of the panel is causing. It’s simple logic.